# Writing a VBA macro to graph

Tags: vba, excel, graph, charts

I am trying to create a chart in Excel using VBA and the chart object. Using the code below I keep getting the error: "Object variable or With block variable not set" I am not exactly sure what this means and would greatly appreciate some guidance. Thanks!

```
Dim newChart As Chart

Private Sub test2_Click()

With newChart
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="Random chart"
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "month1"
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Value = Range("A1:A12")
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "month2"
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).Value = Range("A1:A12")
    .ChartTitle.Text = "random chart"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `newChart` needs to be set to point to an existing Chart object, or to a newly-added chart: your code doesn't do that.

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about doing that? Sorry, I'm new to VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `ChartObjects.Add` method.  If you intend to create a new chart represented by `newChart` variable, you need to tell the application to create the chart because it can't read your mind :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197613(v=office.15).aspx

```
Set newChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(50,50,400,300).Chart
With newChart
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="Random chart"
    .SeriesCollection...
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! Although that line "Set newChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(50,50,400,300)" is now giving me the type mismatch error.

Comment: Add `.Chart` to the end of that statement (see revision above).

Comment: That worked perfectly! I hate to be a pest but the line below is also giving me errors and I just don't know why
.FullSeriesCollection(1).Value = Range("A1:A12")

Object doesn't support this object or property

Comment: Because the `FullSeriesCollection` object doesn't have a `.Value` method :)  See here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj227803(v=office.15).aspx  I have never worked with that particular `FullSeriesCollection` before, but I **think** you simply want `.SeriesCollection(1).Name = ...` etc.

Comment: Ugh it still isn't working, nothing is appearing on the graph, but yeah it's .values not .value with SeriesCollection...oops
But thanks again for all your help! If there was stackoverflow equivalent to reddit gold I would give it to you haha

Comment: Try `SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & Range("A1:A12").Address`

Comment: Hmmmm...doesn't seem to be working, I'll do some experimenting. Thanks again for all your help!